# Divi full screen slider bug

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I added some script and css to make my slider in Divi expand to fill the whole screen.
This normally works but I also replaced the normal nav menu with a full width menu module from divi.
As soon as I do this and launch the page it keeps switching from scroll to without scroll bar.
Like it keeps adjusting the image scale, at some point it stops but often it doesnt stop either.

https://zaveclothing.com/

I have tried making the scroll bar always "on" but that makes it like the script is not on at all.
Making it useless.

This is the CSS <<<<<<<<<<<

```
.et_fullscreen_slider .et_pb_slides,
.et_fullscreen_slider .et_pb_slide,
.et_fullscreen_slider .et_pb_container {
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

This is the script used <<<<<<<<<<<

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $(window).on('load resize', function() {
        $('.et_fullscreen_slider').each(function() {
            et_fullscreen_slider($(this));
        });
    });
    function et_fullscreen_slider(et_slider) {
        var et_viewport_height = $(window).height(),
            et_slider_height = $(et_slider).find('.et_pb_slider_container_inner').innerHeight(),
            $admin_bar = $('#wpadminbar'),
            $main_header = $('#main-header'),
            $top_header = $('#top-header');
        $(et_slider).height('auto');
        if ($admin_bar.length) {
            var et_viewport_height = et_viewport_height - $admin_bar.height();
        }
        if ($top_header.length) {
            var et_viewport_height = et_viewport_height - $top_header.height();
        }
        if (!$('.et_transparent_nav').length && !$('.et_vertical_nav').length) {
            var et_viewport_height = et_viewport_height - $main_header.height();
        }
        if (et_viewport_height > et_slider_height) {
            $(et_slider).height(et_viewport_height);
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Hope someone can help me fix the bug that keeps adjusting the screen as it keeps flipping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the css height to vh unit and add some padding in the container

```
.et_fullscreen_slider .et_pb_slides,
.et_fullscreen_slider .et_pb_slide {
    min-height: 90vh!important;
}
.et_fullscreen_slider .et_pb_container{
    padding-top: 16vw;
    padding-bottom: 16vw;
}
```